# Curse of bad luck, scientific explanations for the magic system

Tags: magic

As far as my limited head can understand, in the realm of quantum everything that can happen will happen or is happening or has already happened.

Example ; you cross the road and the universe splits into an infinite number of universes where you survive or die. Each universe is slightly but uniquely different from another, maybe in two universes the only difference is that you died a split second earlier or your blood splattered on the ground a few nanometers further.

Now how would I make a plausible magic system focused on luck or forced chance, but still based on somewhat science?

Let's say you have a curse of bad luck and you play a gambling game

The odds are 2.0 which means 50% chances of winning, thus over an infinite amount of universes you will win half the time.

Except that you have a curse, which means you lose an infinite amount of times in an infinite amount of universe almost as if in the universes with the curse your chance of winning is multiplied by zero.

Let's call this "**forced chance**"

How do I make such magic system be stable, and not backfire?

I need it to create a curse of bad luck or an item, amulet of bad luck.

Comment: What is your question? Is it just "can I use 'quantum' in my explanation for magic?"

Comment: Does your quantum-multiverse fit into other aspects/elements of the plot, or is it just your explanation for the curse of bad luck? That might affect how much leeway answers have in manipulating it.

Comment: I would recommend reading Greg Egan's novel, Quarantine ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarantine_(Egan_novel) ) for possible inspiration, if you have the availability to. He has quantum-based chance-control of a sort going on.

Comment: A fundamental problem with your question is that "winning" or "bad luck" are human social constructs. The universe does not care if people die, it only sees particles. This means that your magic system will need to be governed by something with human or human-adjacent psychology, meaning divinity or god(s) in this case.

Comment: @Dragongeek eh, considering curses and blessings are already standard part of magic...that's always the case in most works that contain magic. Whatever the mechanism to manipulate luck is, it does rely on purely subjective constructs for what is good or bad. Tripping is bad. Tripping over a gold bar, not as much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to move away from quantum. “Bad luck” requires attaching some kind of mind to the victim. Something intelligent must determine which side of the coin landing up is meaningfully bad for the victim.

But if you want to stay quantum, but like Square-Cube suggested, not have this curse be a killer of universes (which is merely an alternative explanation of the information at hand right now), you could go with Copenhagen or any other theory leading to the following macroscopic effect —

The victim projects an area of influence around him that agitates others, making them jumpy and prone to distraction. This could be done by increasing the random firing of synapses. Or, synaptic firing could be suppressed, thereby dulling minds in the area of effect. Or both. In any case, with everyone nearby distracted and muddle-minded, the amount of “accidents” around the victim goes way up.

The effect could even create tiny physical tremors in the environment near the victim. This causes ropes to slip, bolts to rattle off, welds to break, precariously placed things to shift, or fragile things to just fall apart. To an observer, there are more accidental collapses and breaks around the cursed person.

But this effect is not intelligent. This kind of curse could be a useful tool- for a fee (delivered remotely) I visit your competitor’s factory, or take up a new office on Wall Street.

Answer (score 13):

Magic *destroys universes*.

Until you're left with the ones where the course of action matches what you want.

This is similar to the [Quantum Bogo Sort algorithm](https://wiki.c2.com/?QuantumBogoSort):

> 1. Quantumly randomise the list, such that there is no way of knowing what order the list is in until it is observed. This will divide the universe into O(n!) universes; however, the division has no cost, as it happens constantly anyway.
> 2. If the list is not sorted, destroy the universe. (This operation is left as an exercise to the reader.)
> 3. All remaining universes contain lists which are sorted.

So, the magic does the same:

1. You curse Fred with unluck.
2. Fred throws a coin and calls head.
3. If the result is head then the whole universe is destroyed instantly. You along with it.
4. The remaining universes in the multiverse have tails showing.
5. Fred loses the coin throw.

The same happens for the duration of the curse. As long as Fred is cursed, the *only* universes in existence are the ones where things go badly for him.

Well, I suppose it always goes badly - if Fred wins a coin toss, the whole universe ends. That also seems unlucky.

Comment: "I sure am glad I lost that coin-toss!" -Fred

Comment: @Jedediah Fred, destroyer of universes

Comment: Imagine the universe carnage required for working polymorph by this method.

Comment: This is consistent with an angry and vengeful God punishing people for their wickedness, resulting in a universe of ever increasing suffering and punishment. Applied broadly, hell. All best options are destroyed. Ouch!

Answer (score 5):

You are using the many worlds interpretation of quantum physics. Switch to the Copenhagen interpretation.

The gambling has a wave function which collapses when you observe the outcome of a round of play, i.e.: when the die stop rolling and you look at them. Your curse is an algorhitm that finds the worst outcome beforehand and increases the amplitude of the wave in that point while zeroing it in other points, thus rigging the game.

[Mandatory Dresden Codak](http://dresdencodak.com/2006/02/13/trouble-in-memphis/).

Answer (score 3):

### Luck is in the Eye of the Beholder:

*This isn't a hard-science tag, so this answer is at least partly story based and not absolutely faithful to quantum physics (which is largely theoretical anyway).*

Luck selection by a being is critical to the function of our universe. Since every possible outcome DOES happen, but you can't create infinite universes and endlessly violate conservation, something has to determine which amongst all possible universes is the universe that 'continues' to exist before the alternate universes even come into true existence. The curse is actually an external observer outside of our universe's frame of reference watching our universe unfold. The determination of which universe exists is dependent on how the curse interprets every quantum event as either favorable or unfavorable to the happiness and well-being of an individual in our universe (the cursed one).

There MUST always be one curse in the universe. This curse is transferrable, but can't be stopped. It can also be reversed, since it is dependent on the desired outcome of the observing curse. So in the example of Job, he is cursed for maximum unfavorable outcomes until the curse is 'lifted' (switched to favorable), at which point everything in his life comes up favorable.

Since the vast majority of possible universes are trivially different involving events that have almost nothing to do with the cursed individual, More than one curse (extradimensional observer) can exist and affect the outcome of the universe. Tiny differences in outcome at the other end of the universe might cause small problems with reality, but a common acceptable outcome would likely be achievable. Or perhaps there must be enough curses to stabilize all possible outcomes, and a large total number of curses spread throughout the universe must exist - I can't answer that question, since I can't observe our universe from outside and understand the underlying rules fully.

As long as the outcomes of one curse don't significantly affect the outcomes of another curse, they should be able to exist at the same time. If two people who are cursed should come into proximity, then things get strange. They would either need to join fates (so they had one common curse working for common suffering/good), have one curse negate the other, or they would cancel each other out, possibly destroying the universe as there would no longer be selection and the mass and energy of the universe was divided unsuccessfully across billions of possible alternate realities.
[image]

Comment: Two unlucky cursed guys walk into a bar and decide they will play a game of poker.  Then a bar fight breaks out flipping their table scattering both of their piles of money across the bar. When they try collecting their money they get draw into the fight.  The bouncer then blames them for the fight and kicks them both out leaving all their money on the floor.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Yes, if one of them won, it screws up the bad luck. That would be the combined destiny bad luck if both got screwed, but if they got to be friends, it might be the best luck two cursed guys could ever hope for - and the universe dissolves ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Look at Psychology, not Quantum Physics

> ...but still based on somewhat science

Quantum Physics does not allow you to bad luck curse someone.  It answers questions about how probable an outcome is, but there is no scientific bases for using it to cause a specific outcome.  In contrast, psychology actually can scientifically answer the question about how to change someone's luck.

Psychologist Richard J. Wiseman's research suggests that some people are luckier than others.  How you ask?  Good luck is more than just rolling some dice and hoping for the best possible outcome.  It is about all the things that lead up to that moment right before you strike it big.  And to find that moment means you need to be good at recognizing and exploiting opportunities which is an actual skill. Psychology has identified several ways in which a person's personality determines both how likely they are to be offered an opportunity and how likely they are to seize an opportunity that presents itself.

#### Key Traits Include

**Extroversion:** People who develop more relationships are more likely to be presented with opportunities.

**Low Anxiety:** People with high anxiety tend to be good at focusing on the task at hand, but bad at spotting opportunities to exploit.

**Optimism:** Yup, just believing that you are lucky makes you luckier.  This is because a person who believes they will succeed is more likely to seize an opportunity than someone who believes they will fail.  A poker player who folds every time can only loose, but a player who never folds always has a chance to win.  This concept applies to life as a whole.  A person who starts a business and fails can always come back to start another and another until they have a successful business.  Then everyone calls them lucky for having that million dollar idea, but in reality, a lot of people have million dollar ideas that they never take a chance on, or abandon as soon as things look like they will fail; so, they never get lucky and are perceived as being unlucky 10 years later when they are still working the same dead end job they had in high school.

**Openness to new experiences:** People who seek new experiences inherently come across more opportunities. More opportunities means more room for success.

https://www.inc.com/melissa-chu/want-to-become-luckier-heres-what-you-need-to-do-a.html

#### How Cursing Someone with Bad Luck Works

As it turns out... you can do this in the real world.  You just need to convince someone that they are cursed with bad luck, and their luck will get worse. The fear of bad luck alone will cause their optimism will to be shaken, and anxiety elevated.  Then they will start to hyper focus on bad things which will confirm their bias that they are indeed unlucky so to protect themselves they withdraw socially and stop seeking novel experiences because they fear their bad luck.  Because of all of this, their opportunities for good luck all disappear and all they are left with is the occasional random occurrence that interrupts their routine in ways that they did not want.  And these are the kind of random events that are almost always categorized as bad luck; so, the person is really and effectively cursed with only bad luck.

To convert this into a scientifically based magic system, one could use hypnosis, a mind altering drug, or some method of directly stimulating a person's amygdala to cause them to either temporarily or permanently take on a mind-set that leads to either good or bad luck.