# What genetic enhancements would maximise “luck” in humans?

Tags: science-based, genetics, trans-humanism

In this Sci-if project of mine, bioengineering is now a highly advanced science, nay an art form, and humans are able to enhance their biology using injections of nanomachines which alter their genes. There are myriad genetic enhancements, or genehancements, available to the modern human in this universe.

I would like to design a genehancement that increases the “luck” of the user; naturally I don’t wish to imply there is a single gene responsible for psychic luck in humans, like in *Known Space,* but I was wondering whether there are certain physiological/mental traits that could make a person more prone to seemingly lucky incidents. (Note the patron’s use of the term “seemingly”).

Comment: I think you're getting some good answers, but would suggest that the important thing to focus on is the extent to which luck can be improved by inherent skill, as against stuff which is completely random: a skilled swordsman's "luck" is different from the "luck" which would cause him not to be executed depending on a coin toss. Perhaps the most important thing is a good grasp of the difference, i.e. "here's a situation which I might be able to exploit because of my skill" vs "here's a situation best avoided because it''s random".

Comment: Similar: [Curse of bad luck, scientific explanations for the magic system](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/199652)

Comment: "The more I practice, the luckier I get" -- golf pro Gary Player

Comment: And the difficulty is that the traits that make someone luckier / more adapted to the unusual situation makes them less lucky in some other situation.

Comment: Spoiler for Ringword: what you describe is exactly what happened to humanity in that novel's world, one of the protagonist being the peak of this evolution. There is some interesting philosophy included regarding what "being lucky" actually means.

Comment: well you accepted that question so fast that you maybe loose some valuable answeres - sometimes beeing lazy is equal to beeing lucky

Comment: In this context, is luck opportunity or perception? I think that's a necessary basal distinction to make.

Comment: Why bother about that - literally - tiny detail?

If you want genetic enhancements to maximise luck, why not simply state as fact that Jack or Jill has been enhanced?

Do you not believe that the number of readers who followed what you were saying would be pretty-much in inverse proportion to any real-world details you included?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The was a [study](http://www.richardwiseman.com/resources/The_Luck_Factor.pdf) done to see what made lucky people lucky, the consensus and conclusion was the thing that united lucky people was **the ability to recognize unique opportunities.**

So what does "the ability to recognize unique opportunities" mean.

Well you can break it down into 4 parts mechanically

1. high perception to spot opportunities, other people were getting the same opportunities but often they were not noticing them or not recognizing them for what they are.
2. Thinking quickly enough to recognize that it IS an opportunity and one unlikely to come again.
3. Being intelligent enough to figure out how to exploit said opportunity.
4. The wherewithal to carry out their plan, being able to ignore or not have anxiety was an important aspect of being lucky. .

So you actually can make your people luckier.

Is it a prefect definition no, but it as least precise and falsifiable and gives you a place to start for someone being "lucky"

Comment: Also relevant is selective memory. Somebody who takes 100 chances might get lucky 20 times. Which is 20% "luck". And we generally ignore the unlucky occurrences. So they might seem "more lucky" than somebody who took 10 chances and came up with 3-4 successful ones. So, taking chances just in general can be *perceived* as "lucky" even if you're actually not doing that well.

Comment: @John But that "study" is bull.  Self-selecting candidates, self-reporting results?  Just nope.  All he's describing is their *perception* of luck.  There are people who'd say they're lucky to be alive after an accident.  In fact they were supremely unlucky to be in the accident in the first place, whereas the odds of surviving the accident were actually reasonably good.  His study certainly illustrates how to encourage positive thinking, but it's entirely irrelevant and 100% disconnected from actual luck.  Sorry, but this seriously doesn't answer the question.

Comment: how reliable is "the skeptical inquirer"?

Comment: My browser refused to download the study as a potential security risk. Yikes!

Comment: @njzk2 its  magazine specialized in debunking unscientific claims, so better than most magazines but not as good as a peer reviewed journal.

Comment: @Graham so find another study defining "luck" even your own examples are debatable as to what is an is not luck. An imperfect study is better than none, also better than asking 3 college students which is what you normally get.

Comment: The ability to see and take opportunities is "luck"? Bwahahaha! That's called work.

Comment: @John I'll go with a dictionary definition, thanks. "Random chance". And no, an imperfect study is not necessarily better, because there's a chance someone might incorrectly think it's worth quoting.

Comment: @Graham which one, I know of dozens of definitions for lucky, this one is at least falsifiable and precise.

Comment: A lot of people take up "unique opportunities", and most of them end up being scammed. Your four bullet points don't describe a lucky person, they describe your average ponzi schemer/mlm pusher/crypto bro.

Comment: I can infer that most of the commentators here are unlucky.

Comment: @Mermaker well that would be point 3

Answer (score 16):

Okay - what do you mean by 'luck'?

If we are talking about pure random chance - then the answer would be 'nothing'.

However, if we re-frame what 'luck' is, we might have some interesting possibilities.

1: **Subconscious perception**

Let's assume that what 'luck' is technically, is the ability to subconsciously perceive the world and make better informed decisions without conscious thought.

For an example - you see someone sprinting through a Mine field at full tilt and they don't get blown up - an outside observer would go 'Wow! That person is super Lucky!'

However, the person doing the running, their brain has evolved/mutated to be able to pick up tiny differences in the dirt *without them consciously thinking about it* and so they *naturally* avoid stepping on the displaced dirt of a landmine.

I'm thinking enlarging certain areas of the brain, perhaps a bigger brain stem? I'm not 100% sure of what region of the Brain you would alter - but that's something for you, the writer, to come up with.

2: **unnatural abilities in high-stress situations**

Another interpretation of what 'Luck' is - being able to hit a Million-to-1 baseball throw (for example).

In this interpretation, when someone is in a high-stress situation e.g. they have activated the Fight or Flight response, along with Adrenalin, they also produce a hormone/chemical/macguffin that temporarily increases their dexterity and muscle control.

This allows them to do things that are otherwise considered 'impossible' or extremely difficult. Bonus world-building points - elite level athletes (in your world) train themselves to produce this effect naturally, without the Fight/Flight response.

3: **Unconscious preparation**

Throwing an unusual tool in your car, forgetting about it, then needing that exact tool to help a stranger fix the specific fault in their car that said tool is for - well, that's very lucky.

Here, you could again enhance the part of the brain that deals with future planning - whereby the individual without thinking has a number of items easily on-hand to address some of the most likely scenarios.

Kinda like the old-school Batman TV Show(s) where when facing a particular villain, Batman always had just the right 'tool' on the Bat-Belt to deal with said foe.

Those are the best I got.

Comment: The trick would not be to make these people more perceptive, but to make it so the perceptions are not processed bypass the conscious part of the brain.

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about the ability win the lottery unreasonably often, you're hosed. That's an example of "luck" where no attribute of the participant (short of the prophetic ability to know the future) can influence the outcome of an otherwise random event. If this kind of luck is part of the question, then it's likely a duplicate of a large number of questions on this site about altering probability. Otherwise...

**Absolutely**

Maybe you've heard of a phrase that corresponds to "you were lucky," it's "you dodged a bullet." Humans literally cannot dodge a bullet. *If they don't know the moment the trigger is pulled,* they can't move fast enough to get out of the way.

But that point about the trigger is relevant. It reflects the idea that a human can be *observant.* Combined with reflexes, strength, and focus, what you have is the recipe to appear lucky.

Ergo, some luck could realistically (and is realistically) attributable to circumstances where human attributes can and do influence the outcome of an otherwise random event.

- Observation: enhance eye acuity and a mental disposition to "notice" or, for lack of a more medical phrase, be distracted to a degree by something. Such a person is inclined to notice deer grazing along a highway while driving or that a child has wandered into a situation that is unsafe. We've all noticed people driving on the road who appeared to be oblivious to what's happening around them (and we're sure we're not like them, am I right?). They're the folks who lack this ability.
- Focus: Focus doesn't mean blinders. It means the ability to rationally and calmly think during a moment of chaos and crisis. You've heard of fight-vs-flight? It's not that simple. Some people freeze (flight). Others panic (fight). What we're looking for are the very scary people who don't appear to be phased during moments like this, who can calmly think through it. You know, Bruce Lee types (the movie version, not the real life version.) You could describe this as enhanced brain control over the adrenal response.
- Intuition: is the ability to make the right decision based on limited information. It's benefited by observation and focus. It allows a person to take advantage of a situation, to reasonably "predict" (e.g.) the stock market by noticing a pattern, realizing the potential, and calmly reacting to what's observed. Intuition is an enhancement of the brain's associative memory. It's the mental version of...
- Reflexes: or the ability to "spring into action" (or out of danger). The ability to bring muscles to bear very quickly for a short burst of, well, for lack of a better term, super-human action.
- Strength: If you really want to improve what appears to be enhanced luck, add a slight boost to strength so you can pull someone aside or pull them with you. Nothing says "that was lucky" like one person saying it to the other out of disbelief that they're still alive.
- One more, multi-tasking: The ability to process multiple lines of thought at once so that you're not distracted from your current task when the moment of crisis requires that concentration/focus to resolve it.

While there would be all the medical details that must be dredged up to formally explain how all this can be enhanced, I think that's merely an exercise left to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't improve on nature (or can you?)**

Every person and every living creature that is alive today is here because all their ancestors, from when life began to the present day, were lucky. The unlucky ones died before they were able to reproduce.

You may counter by saying "survival of the fittest" or some such. Yes that is of course important. However, given any two organisms with identical genes, one will be luckier than another.

How can we explain this? Well, of course it's down to pure luck! Or is it?
Firstly luck has to take into account the environment. If we take a batch of identical clones and place them in different environments, then some will survive better than others.

Clearly an organism should seek out the 'best' environment. Yet we know that some species end up in very inhospitable environments indeed. Why are there humans living in icy deserts (the Inuits for example). Are they 'lucky' because they can survive in unhospitable conditions, or are they 'unlucky' to find themselves born there?

**How to proceed**

First of all, you must define precisely what sort of luck to wish you increase. If it is psychic ability then of course you must combine genes from successful psychics.

For example, if you consider luck to apply to people who have won the lottery, then you should selectively breed lottery winners together.

**Conclusion**

Carefully select your desired type of luck and set in action a selective breeding program. When you begin to notice an improvement in luck for that population, it is time to examine their genes and see what they have that is not there in the general population. Implement your gene-modification program to introduce these genes (perhaps by injection) to those you wish to be more lucky.

Answer (score 1):

If you can identify a person who is 'lucky', then you can at least attempt to breed for it.

This may require government control of 'breeding licenses' or some such, or perhaps most adults are limited in allowed offspring, but a lottery allows more.

Niven's Ringworld had a plot point with this.   A character was the descendent of multiple generations of winners of such a lottery.  The downside is that what is 'lucky' for one person may not be 'lucky' for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

If you define 'luck' as:

```
An ability to regularly accomplish goals way beyond one's capability.
```

Then this you can do most easily not by having luck *yourself*, but by having other people willingly help you. Basically, what you're looking for is a genetic modification which makes it easier to make (and keep) more friends.

Answer (score 0):

From a pure genetic perspective, I would give the following descriptions of "luck" :

(this is simply a brainstorming, don't take these thoughts as scientifically proven pls... also most of it breaks down to intuition because there are different types of "luck" if you will)

1. Intuition and pattern recognision. This one is hard to grasp but ultimately comes down to how many experiances you made as a child / young adult. Can u call forth patterns you did in mathematics in the 8th grade? If you can gene-engineer your humans it would probably be wise to enable some kind of light autism. Like aspergers. If somebody has an inherit way of remembering the way they went inside a maze / forrest, it's not really luck but more intuition.
2. Sixth sense. This one can be made via "bioresonance" to define a sci-fi word. People can "read the air" if you will. Either by having an enhanced sense of pheromoneal recognision in others ( which will unintendately "hint" clues to get the correct answere in a social situation like a quiz show ). Also maybe a kind of geomagnetic resonator, like pigeons. If somebody always knows the way north, they can maneuver through a cave system by sheer intuition.
3. People could have specific features and pheromones which make others likely to show them mercy or find them non-threatening. ( for example if 3 out of 10 men should get executed - which one is really "lucky" and which one looks just like a threat to the one that's choosing the men for death sentense )
4. neural co-processor: a kind of ai-powered cpu implant in the brain. it might calculate bullet trajectories in the background, forwarding a roughly ideal shooting angle so that somebody just has to follow. Or the ideal angle of cover in a firefight. Or go even further and calculate f.e. approximated chances in a memory game or the like. The key here is that the wearer of such implants would not need to spent own brain capacity for calculating these values and just makes them up as they go. Whether they know if it was really their own idea to look under memory cards #2 and #345 or if a co-processor simulated many outcomes before hinting them to the person is up to you. But it could, maybe even combined with muscular implants, explain how somebody can hit a basketball in the ring over the head in first try. ( the more expansive the ai is, the better it works )